# Javascript grid to allow editing of contents with multiple lines per row?

Tags: javascript, input, grid

I am writing a web accounting package, which I want to look a bit like QuickBooks or Quicken.
In other words, I want to display (and allow the user to edit) a scrolling list of data records (data probably coming from json). I could use any of the various grids (like datatable) I have found, except that I can't fit that data in 1 table row - it will take 2 rows.
Is there a grid that supports a record taking 2 rows (with different column layouts in each row, and 2 rows of column heading)?
Ideally it would also support detecting when focus moves off an edited record, with an offer to save the record or undo the changes.
I am hoping this is a valid question, not open to discussion of which grid is best for the job, because I haven't been able to find a single suitable grid!

Comment: I think your first step, before anyone can help, is to go into Excel or Paint and mock up a picture of your grid.

Comment: Here is a Quicken screenshot that illustrates the kind of thing (the register on the right)http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quicken_2005_screenshot.png